# Fire event of parent element in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-events

I want to fire an event that is attached to a parent element (`div`) in `iframe`. The event is as follows:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".workingPage", function(event){
        alert("Test");
    });
```

**I've tried the following two methods:**

1:  `parent.$('.workingPage').trigger('keypress');`

2: `$(".workingPage", parent.document).trigger("keypress");`

and I found the first one works, but the second one doesn't. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: the first calls jQuery in parent window, the second doesn't. Different dom

Comment: so it always should be called in the same window?